# Getting a simple Java program to fail cleanly?

Tags: java, crash, formatting

I'm working on a programming assignment, and can't seem to find a simple way around this. We are working on a numerology report and have to accept a date from the user, seperated by spaces and slashes, and then crunch the numbers to form a report. For now, i am just looking for help on inputting the dates. We unfortunately cannot utilize strings yet, so this is the way i had to do it(The print statement at the end is just to validate they are stored in the correct variables).

```
int month, day, year;
       System.out.print ("Birth Date MM / DD / YYYY:");
           Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
               month = in.nextInt();
               char slash1 = in.next() .charAt(0);
               day  = in.nextInt();
               char slash2 = in.next() .charAt(0);
              year = in.nextInt();
       System.out.printf ("%d-%d-%d\n", day,  month, year);
```

When i input a proper date (ex. 12 / 25 / 2013 ), they all get stored and put in the right place as expected. But i would also prefer to have the prompt repeat itself if the specific date format is not met. Where it stands, the program gets an error if the wrong format date is put in. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class ckozeny_Numerology {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        int month, day, year;
        System.out.print ("Birth Date MM / DD / YYYY:");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                month = in.nextInt();
                char slash1 = in.next() .charAt(0);
                day  = in.nextInt();
                char slash2 = in.next() .charAt(0);
                year = in.nextInt();
        System.out.printf ("%d-%d-%d\n", day,  month, year);

  }
}
```

This is the current whole program, really just the first step. A proper date validates, just need to add an error message for if it won't.

Comment: Where is `in` declared? Please show a compiling example.

Comment: take a look at do while loops

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `do while` loop, and can try exception handling if the user put's the string in the wrong place.